# How to separate turtles into ancestors / descendants ? Or 'to the left'/ ' to the right'

Tags: netlogo, bioinformatics

I'm using Netlogo. My model starts from a single cell, and develops into a filament. Ideally, each cell would have a chance of 'dividing', rather than just having the filament grow at the tip. So I'm wondering whether there is a way for each cell to recognize not just its immediate ancestor, but all its ancestors (or its descendants? or all the turtles to its left/right?) and get them to move a patch to make space for the new turtle.

Answer (score 2):

How about giving turtles a lineage as an owned value? Make a global counter and then just add one to that whenever you make a turtle? that way if you have 3 or 300 cells they will each have their own lineage.

If you make a turtle hatch another one, it gives all of it's variables to the new turtle (barring you resetting them like with age or something similar)

```
turtles-own [lineage]
globals [lineage-counter]

   to setup
    create n-of 5 turtles [
       set lineage lineage-counter
       set lineage-counter lineage-counter + 1
    ]
   end
```

You can use that lineage to have turtles kill non-member of their lineage by using:

```
to kill
   set invader one-of turtles here with [lineage != [lineage] of myself]
   if invader != nobody [ask invader [die]]
end
```

Might want to double check that "lineage != [lineage] of myself" bit just incase. That's always wonky for me.

Having a new cell move a patch is just as easy as hatching it 1 patch away

```
to reproduce
  hatch-turtles 1 [setxy ([xcor] of myself + 1) ([ycor] of myself)]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a particularly simple approach, but what do you want to do when you hit an edge?

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 1 [setxy min-pxcor 0 set heading 90]
end

to go
  ask turtles with [random-float 1 < 0.1] [   
    hatch 1 [
      create-link-from myself [hide-link]
      set heading 90
      ask turtles with [pxcor > [pxcor] of myself] [
        fd 1
      ]
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
end
```